# create dynamic link buttons in ListView

Tags: listview, dynamic, controls

I am creating a search using listview. when user enter a word in search, I am generating a listview with the results.

Now, there will be tags in each listview row. When, user clicks the tag, again a search happens using the value in the tag. There may be any number of tags for each listview row. I have to generate linkbuttons for these tags.

Could anyone please guide me on how to create dynamic linkbuttons and access those values for further search.

You can have a look at delicious.com. I need a similar functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any hints as to your programming language?  Quite a few have listviews.

Comment: Which language are you working in?  I take it this is a homework assignment?  I am guessing ASP.NET, but if so, will it go back to the server to be dynamically generated, or done without reloading the page?

Answer (score 0):

the programming language is asp.net 3.5

yes, it will go back to the server with the selected tag value, and a new set of results will be populated based on that value with their respective dynamic link tags...